# Upscaling Image on Hover

Tags: html, css, dom

I want to upscale image on hover, but the problem is I can make it overlapse its own container with `overflow: hidden` only by making `img` absolute positioned, wherefore all `article` content 'thinks' that there is no image in container.

```css
article {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  color: #484848;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 2rem auto 0 auto;
  width: 60vw;
}

section {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  transition: 0.2s linear;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}

img:hover {
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale( 1.5 );
}
```

```html
<article>
  <section>
    <img src=https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/repeating-geometrical-square-background-pattern-vector-graphic-design-from-random-rotated-squares-with-opacity-effect_1164-1119.jpg>
    <img src=https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/repeating-geometrical-square-background-pattern-vector-graphic-design-from-random-rotated-squares-with-opacity-effect_1164-1119.jpg>
  </section>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</article>
```

How to freeze all `article` content after `img` becomes absolute positioned?

Please, no JS solutions.

Answer (score 1):

`float:left` on `p` done the work!.

```css
article {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  color: #484848;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 2rem auto 0 auto;
  width: 60vw;
}

section {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  float:left;
}

img {
  transition: 0.2s linear;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}

img:hover {
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale( 1.5 );
}
```

```html
<article>
  <section>
    <img src=https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/repeating-geometrical-square-background-pattern-vector-graphic-design-from-random-rotated-squares-with-opacity-effect_1164-1119.jpg>
    <img src=https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/repeating-geometrical-square-background-pattern-vector-graphic-design-from-random-rotated-squares-with-opacity-effect_1164-1119.jpg>
  </section>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</article>
```

As you want `p` to don't interact with images then before hover text will also don't interact with image and don't change it's own position.

Comment: When I hover the first image, the second one moves under the first one.

Comment: you can create two div.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to put the element you want to animate into a container, and then trigger the animation when you hover the container.

```css
article {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  color: #484848;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 2rem auto 0 auto;
  width: 60vw;
}

section {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  transition: 0.2s linear;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}

.image-container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.image-container:hover > img {
  transform: scale( 1.5 );
}
```

```html
<article>
  <section>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src=https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/repeating-geometrical-square-background-pattern-vector-graphic-design-from-random-rotated-squares-with-opacity-effect_1164-1119.jpg>  
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src=https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/repeating-geometrical-square-background-pattern-vector-graphic-design-from-random-rotated-squares-with-opacity-effect_1164-1119.jpg>
     </div>
  </section>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</article>
```

Comment: Image have to ignore `overflow: hidden` and overlapse over `article` element.

Comment: Then don't have `overflow: hidden` on the article element?

Comment: If I will do not set `overflow: hidden`, `img` in its default state will overlapse container.

Comment: No, it wont. I updated my answer by removing `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: Okay, now check what happens if paragraph would contain only few words — images will overlapse the container.

Comment: Put a min-height on `article`? Not the smoothest solution.

Comment: No, it doesn't fit my needs.